# Why doesn't a void function print anything in C++?

Tags: c++

Im just starting to learn C++. While writing a simple calculator, I found that when calling a void function, it doesn't print when it should. I have simplified the code to better represent my problem.

```C++
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void helloguys()
{
    cout << "test";
}


int main()
{
    cout << "This is a ";
    void helloguys();
    cout << " guys.";
}
```

I expected to get "This is a test guys.", but all I got is "This is a guys."
The compiler never reported any kind of problems.

Comment: `void helloguys();` is a function declaration, not a function call. Read your book more carefully, don't try to learn C++ by guessing.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves so many minus votes. The question is clear, it comes with a working example and the expectations of the poster are well formulated.

Comment: @Chiel 1) "-2" isn't "so many". 2) Most likely people downvoted on the basis of "This question does not show any research effort".

Comment: @Chiel The expectations of the Asker are quickly disabused by a bit of reading in any credible programming text.

Answer (score 5):

Try removing `void` before your function call:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "This is a ";
    helloguys();
    cout << " guys.";
}
```

- `helloguys();` will **call** the function.
- `void helloguys();` is a function **prototype**, not a call.